# Deserialize Xml with empty elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Trying to deserialize some xml snippits from a vendor into objects.  The problem is that I'm getting an invalid format on every empy element tag.  I can deserialize the object no problem when all of the elements have values. Or the empty elements are ommitted.

Xml Snippit:

> <foo>
> <propOne>1</propOne>
> <propTwo />
> </foo>

C# Class:

```
[Serialilbe()]     
public class foo
{ 
   public foo(){}
   [XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
   public int? propOne {get;set;} 
   [XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
   public int? propTwo {get;set;}   
 }
```

Is there a setting on the class I can make to adjust the parsing?
or
Is there an easy way I can apply xsl to remove these elements?
or 
Should I use regEx to remove the empty elements be fore desrializing?
or 
an even better way?

Comment: Are you serializing via the same interface (I.E. XmlSerializer class)?

Comment: As a side note, the XMLSerializer is close to being deprecated.  You might consider using the DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most uniform way to clean out these nodes appears to be to add a RegEx filter to the deserializer.

> ```
>     public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml){
>         XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
>         string cleanXml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"<[a-zA-Z].[^(><.)]+/>",
>                                         new MatchEvaluator(RemoveText));
>         MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream((new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(cleanXml));
>         XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
>         return (T)xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
>     }
> ```

```
  static string RemoveText(Match m) { return "";}
```

Comment: What if there is a complete element without a value: `<Element></Element>`. I've written my own logic to remove this, but it's too slow and the file too big. Can we write RegEx to detect this?

Answer (score 11):

Another option if you've not got control over the inbound XML is to work around this by having the deserializer pretend that the variable is a string:

```
[Serializable()]     
public class foo
{ 
  public foo(){}

  [XmlElement("propOne")]
  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
  public string propOneString {get;set;}

  [XmlIgnore]
  private int? propOneInternal = null;
  [XmlIgnore]
  private bool propOneSet = false;

  [XmlIgnore]
  public int? propOne
  {
    get
    {
      if (!propOneSet)
      {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propOneString)
        {
          propOneInternal = int.Parse(propOneString);
        }
        //else leave as pre-set default: null
        propOneSet = true;
      }
      return propOneInternal;
    }
    set { propOneInternal = value; }
  }
}
```

The Deserialiser is happy to parse a string element when it's empty, so you make use of that.

It's not particularly nice, but it'll do if you've only got one or 2 tags to cover

Comment: EDIT: propOneString should obviously be a string, not an int :)

Comment: Yup, easiest way for me. Just had one tag to deal with. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

See this article: [Can XmlSerializer deserialize into a Nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306877/can-xmlserializer-deserialize-into-a-nullableint)

In a nutshell your Xml should look like this if you want to use Nullable types:

```
<foo xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
<propOne>1</propOne>
<propTwo xsi:nil='true'/>
</foo>
```

The two changes are adding the namespace, and explicitly setting xsi:nil to true on the null element.

If you don't have control over your Xml there is a more advanced technique described here:  [Using XmlSerializer to deserialize into a Nullable](https://web.archive.org/web/20110825092054/http://alexscordellis.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-xmlserializer-to-deserialize-into.html)

Comment: The "Using XmlSerializer to deserialize into a Nullable" link is dead. One way to do this is to implement IXmlSerializable and convert empty to null inside ReadXml(). Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/625463/1034683

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, why don't you parse the xml explictly using XmlDocument and XPath? Use XPath to explictly access each xml node e.g.

```
XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode ("foo/PropOne");
if (node != null)
{
     propOneValue = node.innerText;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming he wants to deserialize into a class/type and not have to pull the values one by one.