# Outputting Empty XML tags for ints and Lists

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a C# class which is outputted from a service as XML. Under certain circumstances I wish to set most of the properties of this class to such values that they return empty XML tags. I want the names of the properties to show up in the XML output but as empty tags.

Now for the strings this appears to be trivial enough I can set them to be equal to `String.Empty`. However I'm scratching my head as to what to do with a property of type `int` and another that is of type `List<DateTime>`.

I cannot alter the class in question but if it helps matters the int property is decorated with an `XmlElement` annotation and the list has a `XmlArrayItem` annotation.

Comment: So empty value in the xml?

Comment: Why can you not modify the xml and set the `InnerText` property of the node to empty?

Comment: Use same as strings since xml doesn't distinguish between strings and int for tab values.

Comment: Silly question but does the class your accessing have any documentation associated with what is an acceptable input? Have you experimented with passing in 0 or negative values for the int or a list of nulls for the List<DateTime> property? Sometimes you have to blow something up to see what it's made of... :oP (BTW don't do on production!)

Comment: For the `int`, you'll need to make the property nullable, and follow instructions from [Deserializing empty xml attribute value into nullable int property using XmlSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1295697/3744182) or (Deserialize Xml with empty elements in C#)[http://stackoverflow.com/q/2966056/3744182].  For the `List<DateTime>`, what is the problem?  If I serialize an empty list I get `<RootObject><DateTimes /></RootObject>` which seems to be what you want.