# Is XmlReader.ReadString deprecated or obsoleted?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm wanting to use `System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadString()`, but I noticed it doesn't show up in Intellisense because the function is decorated with `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`.  Despite not being marked as `[Obsolete]`, I assume Microsoft doesn't want me to use it.

I can't find any mention of this on MSDN.  What should I be using instead?  In ILSpy I see `ReadElementContentAsString()` and `ReadContentAsString()`.  Is this what I want to use instead?  I am using .Net 4.5.

In case it's relevant, this question was prompted by this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/625463/47589

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It [isn't deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I think your reasoning is correct. The framework developers likely marked it as `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` so that it doesn't show up in intellisense, and "nudges" you to use a better alternative, which maybe `ReadContentAsString`.

According to [C# In a Nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=_Y0rWd-Q2xkC&pg=PA402&lpg=PA402&dq=ReadContentAsString%20vs%20readstring&source=bl&ots=R8ICV7SKZm&sig=XiF56nIeHGNPnXj85lrbvcO4nZ0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PGLYUr65Kc_6oATk6YDABA&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> `ReadString` and `ReadElementString` behave like `ReadContentAsString`
>   and `ReadElementContentAsString`, except that they throw an
>   `Exception` if there's more than a *single* text node within the
>   element. In general, these methods should be avoided, as they throw an
>   exception if an element contains a comment.

Maybe that's why you are seeing `ReadContentAsString` in the IL, because the framework is internally converting all calls to `ReadString` to `ReadContentAsString` and the Framework developers intentionally hid `ReadString` from the intellisense.

See related : [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable was written by idiots](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/08/SystemComponentModelEditorBrowsable-was-written-by-idiots.aspx)

Comment: What is the better alternative?