# What's the Difference Between `ReadString` Vs `ReadContentAsString` in XmlReader Class?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I noticed in some open source code, the usage of `System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadString()` to parse Xml. But when I tried to use it in a console app just to check it out (I'm curious girl by nature) I didn't get any intellisense when I press `.` against an `XmlReader` class instance variable.

I got really intrigued and inspected the `MSIL` using **ILDASM**. That's when I noticed that this class method is decorated with

`[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`

Also noticed that the call I made to `ReadString()` has been converted to another method that goes by the name of `ReadContentAsString`. I am able to find zero documentation on MSDN on why the Microsoft programmer made this decision.

Anyone? I really want to know so that I am calling the right method in my production code.

Also don't want any future developers who see my code dismiss me as a dummy because I am a girl and a developer (rare combination from what I see in a highly male dominated profession ;)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174168/is-xmlreader-readstring-deprecated-or-obsoleted) appears to ask the same question but includes reasoning why.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what it is you are trying to do (i.e. what prompted the question)?

Answer (score 0):

You should have started by perusing the official documentation for the two functions:

[`ReadString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readstring):

> reads the contents of an element or text node as a string. However, we recommend that you use the [`ReadElementContentAsString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring) method instead, because it provides a more straightforward way to handle this operation.

[`ReadContentAsString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasstring):

> Reads the text content at the current position as a `String` object.

Whereas `ReadString()` works only with two types of node—*text* and *element*—`ReadContentAsString()` handles a whole bunch of them, including *CDATA*,  *whitespace*, and *comment*, but not *element*! I consider the latter method rather confusing overgeneralised, with its rules for the processing of different node types and the need for the read to be *inside* an element rather than at the start of it.

I consider `ReadString()` the more convenient method because one need only position the reader at the start of an element in order to read its contents. The recommendation to use [`ReadElementContentAsString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring) is in my opinion unjustified, because the recommended method:

> reads the start tag, the contents of the element, and moves the reader past the end element tag.

As you see, it is asymmetrical and automatically skips the closing tag, putting the reader at the node that follows. This behavior may easily break certain simple patterns, such as scanning with selective reading. Consider the following code that scans a sequence of "cell" elements in a *XML* file and reads the contents of only those that have a certain attribute set to the value `ReadMe!`

```
string attrib;
string content;
while( NextCell( reader, out attrib ) )
{  if( attrib != "ReadMe!" ) continue;
    ReadCell( reader, out content );
}
```

In my case, `NextCell()` leaves the reader at the beginning of a cell element or returns false. `ReadCell()` always leaves the reader at the closing tag of the cell element last read. It uses `ReadString()` to do that. If it employed `ReadElementContentAsString()` the reader would be left at the start of the next cell and `NextCell()` would jump over it to the cell after it.